# pandas count over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, graphlab

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
Measure1 Measure2 Measure3 ...
0        1         3
1        3         2
3        0
```

I'd like to count the occurrences of the values over the columns to produce:

```
Measure Count Percentage
0       2     0.25
1       2     0.25
2       1     0.125
3       3     0.373
```

With

```
outcome_measure_count = cdss_data.groupby(key_columns=['Measure1'],operations={'count': agg.COUNT()}).sort('count', ascending=True)
```

I only get the first column (actually using graphlab package, but I'd prefer pandas)

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the counts by flattening the df using `ravel` and `value_counts`, from this you can construct the final df:

```
In [230]:
import io
import pandas as pd
​
t="""Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
0        1         3
1        3         2
3        0        0"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
df

Out[230]:
   Measure1  Measure2  Measure3
0         0         1         3
1         1         3         2
2         3         0         0

In [240]:    
count = pd.Series(df.squeeze().values.ravel()).value_counts()
pd.DataFrame({'Measure': count.index, 'Count':count.values, 'Percentage':(count/count.sum()).values})

Out[240]:
   Count  Measure  Percentage
0      3        3    0.333333
1      3        0    0.333333
2      2        1    0.222222
3      1        2    0.111111
```

I inserted a `0` just to make the df shape correct but you should get the point

Comment: And when this part is part of a bigger df? So I need to specify the columns? When using: count = pd.Series(cdss_data['measure1','measure2'].squeeze().values.ravel()).value_counts() I get an error (cdss_data is my df)

Comment: You need to double subscript `count = pd.Series(cdss_data[['measure1','measure2']].squeeze().values.ravel()).value_count‌​s()`

Comment: Great! Is there a way to force the order of the column and order of the rows?

Comment: You can use fancy indexing e.g.: `desired_col_list = [a,b,c,d]` `df = df.ix[:,desired_col_list]` for example

Answer (score 0):

```
In [68]: df=DataFrame({'m1':[0,1,3], 'm2':[1,3,0], 'm3':[3,2, np.nan]})

In [69]: df
Out[69]:
   m1  m2   m3
0   0   1  3.0
1   1   3  2.0
2   3   0  NaN

In [70]: df=df.apply(Series.value_counts).sum(1).to_frame(name='Count')

In [71]: df
Out[71]:
     Count
0.0    2.0
1.0    2.0
2.0    1.0
3.0    3.0

In [72]: df.index.name='Measure'

In [73]: df
Out[73]:
         Count
Measure
0.0        2.0
1.0        2.0
2.0        1.0
3.0        3.0

In [74]: df['Percentage']=df.Count.div(df.Count.sum())

In [75]: df
Out[75]:
         Count  Percentage
Measure
0.0        2.0       0.250
1.0        2.0       0.250
2.0        1.0       0.125
3.0        3.0       0.375
```