# Pandas count all occurrences on different columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data frame similar to this one

    `GRP      HOST1     HOST2     HOST3   FILESIZE
0     0      srv39      srv45    srv47  203498176
1     1     srv102      srv36    srv38  452763956
2     1     srv101      srv36    srv45  453277268
3     1     srv101      srv34    srv45  448174741
4     1      srv36      srv49    srv50  452728577
5     2     srv100      srv47    srv48  454617541
6     2     srv100      srv45    srv49  454617541
7     2      srv38      srv49    srv47  454617541`

Now what I would like to achieve is count all occurrences that I have across  HOST1 HOST2 and HOST3 column grouped by the GRP column, like this

`--
   GRP     HOST   count
     1   srv101      2 
          srv36      3`

It would be perfect if I would be able to sum the value of the FILESIZE column.
I was trying to shape a solution using suggestions that I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045837/pandas-count-over-multiple-columns), but I have not been able to get the count grouped by GRP.

Any suggestion about which would be the best approach to obtain the results that I need with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape anf then aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = (df.melt(id_vars='GRP', value_vars=['HOST1','HOST2','HOST3'], value_name='HOST')
        .groupby(['GRP', 'HOST'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
    GRP    HOST  count
0     0   srv39      1
1     0   srv45      1
2     0   srv47      1
3     1  srv101      2
4     1  srv102      1
5     1   srv34      1
6     1   srv36      3
7     1   srv38      1
8     1   srv45      2
9     1   srv49      1
10    1   srv50      1
11    2  srv100      2
12    2   srv38      1
13    2   srv45      1
14    2   srv47      2
15    2   srv48      1
16    2   srv49      2
```

If want `sum` of column `FILESIZE` use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars=['GRP', 'FILESIZE'], value_vars=['HOST1','HOST2','HOST3'], value_name='HOST')
        .groupby(['GRP', 'HOST'])['FILESIZE']
        .agg(['size','sum'])
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df1)
    GRP    HOST  size         sum
0     0   srv39     1   203498176
1     0   srv45     1   203498176
2     0   srv47     1   203498176
3     1  srv101     2   901452009
4     1  srv102     1   452763956
5     1   srv34     1   448174741
6     1   srv36     3  1358769801
7     1   srv38     1   452763956
8     1   srv45     2   901452009
9     1   srv49     1   452728577
10    1   srv50     1   452728577
11    2  srv100     2   909235082
12    2   srv38     1   454617541
13    2   srv45     1   454617541
14    2   srv47     2   909235082
15    2   srv48     1   454617541
16    2   srv49     2   909235082
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `stack` , then follow with `groupby` and `size`

```
s=df.set_index('GRP')[['HOST1','HOST2','HOST3']].stack().to_frame('HOST')
s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(level=0),s.HOST]).size()
Out[229]: 
GRP  HOST  
0    srv39     1
     srv45     1
     srv47     1
1    srv101    2
     srv102    1
     srv34     1
     srv36     3
     srv38     1
     srv45     2
     srv49     1
     srv50     1
2    srv100    2
     srv38     1
     srv45     1
     srv47     2
     srv48     1
     srv49     2
dtype: int64
```

If you need sum

```
s=df.set_index(['GRP','FILESIZE'])[['HOST1','HOST2','HOST3']].stack().to_frame('HOST').reset_index(level=1)
s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(level=0),s.HOST.values]).FILESIZE.agg(['count','sum'])
```